# Configuring Remote Connections to Mono Asp-State Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono, session-state-server

I am trying to migrate an Asp State Server from Windows to Linux Box, I have installed **Mono** and **XSP** after starting the **asp-state4**, while trying to connect to the Server it is showing the below mentioned message.

```
Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. 
Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client 
and server ports are the same. If the server is on a remote machine, please 
ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters
\AllowRemoteConnection. If the server is on the local machine, and if the 
before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state 
server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the 
server name.
```

I know how to set the same in Windows but in Linux Box with XSP how do you set to allow remote connections ?

I tested with telnet to check the connectivity between my machine and the Linux Box when the asp-state is running in Linux, and it is connecting.

Any help to configure the remote connections for asp-state in Linux would be highly appreciated.

- NET Framework [Version]: 4.0
- Monodevelop [Version]: 3.0.3.2
- Mono-xsp [Version]: 2.10-2.4
- Ubuntu [Version]: 12.04 LTS